# Populate table from other table ID

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have two tables and I want that when a user clicks a row from one table that value will be used to populate the next table with corresponding rows.

The value from the first table is being retrieved ok, and the query in which to populate the second query is working ok, but for some reason it won't populate the second table with the first value.

The view

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered tabular_datable-condensed table-hover" id="statsTable"> 

  <tr class="success">
  <th>Match ID</th>
  <th>Team</th>
  <th>Event</th>
  <th>Match Time</th>


  </tr>
    <tbody class="searchable2">
   <tr class="clickable-row">

<?php foreach ($table2 as $row): {?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['match_id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['team_id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['event_name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['event_time'];?></td>


        <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
```

the javascript

```
  $('#choose_match tbody tr').hover(function() {

  $(this).addClass('hover-row');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover-row');
}).on('click', function() {

   $('#choose_match tr').not(this).removeClass('click-row')
  $(this).toggleClass('click-row');

var match_id = ($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(5)').text());
alert(match_id);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseurl+ '/Match_Analysis/match_choice',        
    dataType: "text",
        data: {match_id: match_id},
        success: function (data){}



  });
});
```

controller

```
    public function match_choice(){
      $data = $this->Match_Analysis_model->statsTable();

      }
    public function index(){
      $data['table2'] = $this->Match_Analysis_model->statsTable();

}
```

model

```
 function statsTable(){

    $match_id=$this->input->post('match_id');

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT match_id, team_id, event_name, event_time FROM match_event WHERE match_id='$match_id'");
    //$this->db->order_by("event_time");

    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;


  }
```

Comment: The click is on **#choose_match tbody tr**, but I see only **#statsTable** table. And the whole javascript (jquery) part is very ugly, there is no success code and no second table (so we don't see, what are you trying to do).

Comment: @shaggy thanks for the reply, that table shown is the second table which should be populated from table 1 value. I didn't add table 1 because I know I am retrieving the value ok I can print to console etc.

Comment: show us what does your ajax do on success. You are saying that you are retrieving values, but your match_choice inside your controller isn't returning any data.

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner so I'm really not competent in this but in index in the controller I am using  $data['table2'] = $this->Match_Analysis_model->statsTable(); to update the table. The ajax shows it is posting the 'match_id' value but it is not being received by the model.

Comment: Yes, but: 1. you are calling **match_choice**, not **index** of controller. 2. you are not echoing anything (or loading a view), so you can't have any output in your console.

Comment: Ok, obviously this is way over my head but if i add an alert("success") to ajax success i get the alert and if I var_dump the match_id in the model I get the correct id. I just don't understand why the table won't update with the new information...

Comment: Because you don't have any code in your ajax.success that will update your second table.

Comment: Lol ok I'm terrible at this i know, could you give me a hint even? I have no idea how to do this. the only other thing I know i could do would be to forget about trying to populate with a query and use jquery to hide certain rows.

Comment: Inside of your success function (in the AJAX call), could you add console.log( data ) and post what is being returned from it?